# Send edittext values to php json webservice android

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

I have four edit texts and button and php json webservice in my application.I'm trying to send those edit text values to php page using json.if values reach php page it will return `success=1`,else it return `success=2`but when I click on submit button application force close.this is my code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mhost=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_host);
        mdb=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_db);
        muser=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_user);
        mpassword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_password);

        mConnection=(Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);
        mConnection.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        new Connect().execute();

                    }
                });
        } 
    class Connect extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String HOST=mhost.getText().toString();
                String USER=muser.getText().toString();
                String DB=mdb.getText().toString();
                String PASSWORD=mpassword.getText().toString();

                List<NameValuePair> params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nfc_tag", HOST));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("meter_reading", USER));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reading_datetime", DB));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_name", PASSWORD));


                JSONObject json=jp.makeHttpRequest(connection_url, "POST", params);

                try {

                    int success=json.getInt(Tag_success);
                    if(success==1){

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected :-)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }else{

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Connected :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

        }
```

Json Parser

```
public class JsonParser {

    static InputStream IS=null;
    static JSONObject JB=null;
    static String json="";

    public JsonParser(){


    }
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url,String method,List<NameValuePair> params){
        try {

            if(method=="POST"){

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            }else if(method=="GET"){
                 DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                 String paramaString =URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                 url +="?"+paramaString;
                 HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet(url);

                 HttpResponse httpresponse=httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                 HttpEntity httpEntity=httpresponse.getEntity();
                 IS=httpEntity.getContent();

            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(IS,"iso-8859"),8);
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            String line=null;
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            IS.close();
            json=sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("Buffer Error","Connection Error"+e.toString());
        }
        try {
            JB=new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("JSON Parser", e.toString());
        }

        return JB;
    }
```

PHP Script

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$host=$_POST['nfc_tag'];
$user=$_POST['meter_reading'];
$db=$_POST['reading_datetime'];
$password=$_POST['image_name'];

$response=array();


if($host){

$response['success']=1;
}else{
$response['success']=2;
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

LogCat

```
09-14 15:58:40.823: E/Buffer Error(11735): Connection Errorjava.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/JSON Parser(11735): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735): Exception
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735): Process: com.example.test_webservice, PID: 11735
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735):    at com.example.test_webservice.MainActivity$Connect.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:114)
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735):    at com.example.test_webservice.MainActivity$Connect.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-14 15:58:40.833: E/AndroidRuntime(11735):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Comment: could you please post the logcat too..

Comment: @Lal check my edited post please

Comment: please post the remaining lines in your logcat too

Comment: @Lal please check my update

Comment: what is line no 114 in MainActivity.java?

Comment: @Lal ` int success=json.getInt(Tag_success); `

Comment: there may not be an entry named `Tag_success` in `json`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
include('connection.php');
$host=$_POST['nfc_tag'];
$user=$_POST['meter_reading'];
$db=$_POST['reading_datetime'];
$password=$_POST['image_name'];
$response=array();
if($host != NULL){
$response['success']=1;
}else{
$response['success']=2;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```